# Why does result depend on procedure in my calculation of surface area using Guldin?

Tags: secondary-education, geometry, students-mistakes

At present, I teach Guldin's rules for surface and volume of rotation, and give an example task from the textbook. The textbook uses procedure 1 (below) for calculation (below), but I advocate that you should be able to use procedure 2 as well. 
Where is the flaw in my argument for equivalence between the two procedures (or in my calculation of the surface area)?

Guldin's first rule is also known as [Pappus first centroid theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem), 
and states that a plane figure creates an areal when rotated that is the product of the distance the centroid is moved and the length of the figure.

I should therefore get the same resulting area when I rotate a triangle, as when I rotate the three segments making up the sides of the triangle.
Thus, I must do something wrong when I do not get that. Here are my calculations, provided triangle $ABC$, where $A=(1,1)$, $B=(1,4)$ og $C=(4,3)$.

In procedure 1, I shall calculate the contribution from each segment, then add.
In procedure 2, I shal find the centroid and the perimeter and "directly" calculate the surface area of the volume of rotation.

**Procedure 1**: 
$r_{AB}=1,L_{AB}=3,A_{AB}=2\cdot\pi\cdot r_{AB}\cdot L_{AB}=6\pi$.
$r_{BC}=\frac{5}{2},L_{BC}=\sqrt{(4-1)^2+(3-4)^2}=\sqrt{10},A_{BC}=2\cdot\pi\cdot r_{BC}\cdot L_{BC}=5\pi\sqrt{10}$.
$r_{AC}=\frac{5}{2},L_{AC}=\sqrt{(4-1)^2+(3-1)^2}=\sqrt{13},A_{AC}=2\cdot\pi\cdot r_{AC}\cdot L_{AC}=5\pi\sqrt{13}$.

Consequently, the total surface area amounts to $A_1=A_{AB}+A_{BC}+A_{AC}=\pi\left(6+5\sqrt{10}+5\sqrt{13}\right)$.

**Procedure 2:**
Triangle $ABC$ perimeter $L=L_{AB}+L_{BC}+L_{AC}=3+\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{13}$.
Radius of rotation for triangle $ABC$: $r=2$.

Total surface area: $A_2=2\pi r L=4\pi\left(3+\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{13}\right)$.

I expected $A_1=A_2$, but I get $A_1=A_2+\pi\left(-6+\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{13}\right)$.
[image: Calculation of surface area of triangle rotated around the y-axis]

Comment: This question is really a mathematical one, and not about pedagogy/education. Better fits on Mathematics SE. Vote to close.

Comment: It's so tempting to give the answer though :D

Comment: @ChrisCunningham you can do so over there https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2744680/why-two-different-results-to-surface-areal-calculation-using-guldin

Comment: Ha -- fair point. Interesting that I never considered it. Thanks @quid

Comment: [Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2751704/201335) in Mathematics by @ChrisCunningham was **exactly** what I was looking for: Area centroid may differ from periphery (linear) centroid.